# node/123 is not redirecting to its alias

Tags: redirection, uri

I have something going on in my site that I didn't notice until now. I am using the [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module to create multiple sites within one Drupal instance, so I'm thinking that may have something to do with it, since it's my only site this is happening to.

If I create a node, Drupal creates the page like normal i.e.: www.mysite.com/node/123. I can then give that URL an alias like "foo" and I can successfully go to that page by going to www.mysite.com/foo and it resolves to the correct page. HOWEVER, if I go to www.mysite.com/node/123 in the address bar, Drupal is not auto redirecting to "www.mysite.com/foo". It just stays at www.mysite.com/node/123 in the address bar. Does anyone know what could be causing this? I do have the redirect module installed. Also, my .htaccess files are in place and are the same as all my other sites that don't have this issue.

Comment: Do you have path auto installed in your instance?

Comment: Yes I do. Also I forgot to mention I am using Drupal 7.43 and Domain Access version 7.x-3.12.

Comment: Install the [Global Redirect module](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect), it should solve your problem.